# C# StreamReader detect &#x2; encoding of an XML File

Tags: c#, .net, xml

In my xml file i have data like this :

```
<Data>
    <Field>
        <Name>BarcodeCapture_0</Name>
        <Type>SimpleIndex</Type>
        <DataType>DataMatrix</DataType>
        <Value>DEA&#x2;"&#x1;¡CV°)Ñ     &#x2;vÃµ Fƒ´     20100410050</Value>
    </Field>
</Data>
```

Im using a class that extend from StreamReader, i override reading methodes to prevent inaccepted characters like  character.

This is the class

```
public class CustomStreamReader : StreamReader
    {
        private const int EOF = -1;

        public CustomStreamReader(Stream stream) : base(stream)
        {
        }

        public CustomStreamReader(string path) : base(path)
        {
        }

        public CustomStreamReader(string path, Encoding encoding) : base(path, encoding)
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get whether an integer represents a legal XML 1.0 or 1.1 character. See
        /// the specification at w3.org for these characters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlVersion">
        /// The version number as a string. Use "1.0" for XML 1.0 character
        /// validation, and use "1.1" for XML 1.1 character validation.
        /// </param>
        public static bool IsLegalXmlChar(string xmlVersion, int character)
        {
            switch (xmlVersion)
            {
                case "1.1": // http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets
                    {
                        return
                        !(
                             character <= 0x8 ||
                             character == 0xB ||
                             character == 0xC ||
                            (character >= 0xE && character <= 0x1F) ||
                            (character >= 0x7F && character <= 0x84) ||
                            (character >= 0x86 && character <= 0x9F) ||
                             character > 0x10FFFF
                        );
                    }
                case "1.0": // http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets
                    {
                        return
                        (
                             character == 0x9 /* == '\t' == 9   */          ||
                             character == 0xA /* == '\n' == 10  */          ||
                             character == 0xD /* == '\r' == 13  */          ||
                            (character >= 0x20 && character <= 0xD7FF) ||
                            (character >= 0xE000 && character <= 0xFFFD) ||
                            (character >= 0x10000 && character <= 0x10FFFF)
                        );
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                            ("xmlVersion", string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid XML version."));
                    }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get whether an integer represents a legal XML 1.0 character. See the  
        /// specification at w3.org for these characters.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool IsLegalXmlChar(int character)
        {
            return CustomStreamReader.IsLegalXmlChar("1.0", character);
        }

        public override int Read()
        {
            // Read each character, skipping over characters that XML has prohibited

            int nextCharacter;

            do
            {
                // Read a character

                if ((nextCharacter = base.Read()) == EOF)
                {
                    // If the character denotes the end of the file, stop reading

                    break;
                }
            }

            // Skip the character if it's prohibited, and try the next

            while (!CustomStreamReader.IsLegalXmlChar(nextCharacter));

            return nextCharacter;
        }

        public override int Peek()
        {
            // Return the next legl XML character without reading it 

            int nextCharacter;

            do
            {
                // See what the next character is 

                nextCharacter = base.Peek();
            }
            while
            (
                // If it's prohibited XML, skip over the character in the stream
                // and try the next.

                !CustomStreamReader.IsLegalXmlChar(nextCharacter) &&
                (nextCharacter = base.Read()) != EOF
            );

            return nextCharacter;

        } // method


        // The following methods are exact copies of the methods in TextReader, 
        // extracting by disassembling it in Refelctor

        public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            if (buffer == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
            }
            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }
            if (count < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
            }
            if ((buffer.Length - index) < count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            int num = 0;
            do
            {
                int num2 = this.Read();
                if (num2 == -1)
                {
                    return num;
                }
                buffer[index + num++] = (char)num2;
            }
            while (num < count);
            return num;
        }

        public override int ReadBlock(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            int num;
            int num2 = 0;
            do
            {
                num2 += num = this.Read(buffer, index + num2, count - num2);
            }
            while ((num > 0) && (num2 < count));
            return num2;
        }

        public override string ReadLine()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while (true)
            {
                int num = this.Read();
                switch (num)
                {
                    case -1:
                        if (builder.Length > 0)
                        {
                            return builder.ToString();
                        }
                        return null;

                    case 13:
                    case 10:
                        if ((num == 13) && (this.Peek() == 10))
                        {
                            this.Read();
                        }
                        return builder.ToString();
                }
                builder.Append((char)num);
            }
        }

        public override string ReadToEnd()
        {
            int num;
            char[] buffer = new char[0x1000];
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(0x1000);
            while ((num = this.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                builder.Append(buffer, 0, num);
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }

    }
```

In XML deserialization side :

```
CustomStreamReader fStream_scanTransaction_XML = new CustomStreamReader(scanTransactionFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ScanTransaction));
ScanTransaction result = ScanTransaction)s.Deserialize(fStream_scanTransaction_XML);
```

The problem is that StreamReader cannot detect  encoding, so it not deleting this character and the Xml deserialization faild.

Comment: just suggestion: convert string of any encoding to byte array, then to base64 strings, and the xml only store the base64 string and the encoding types. and it will be safe to convert back.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to deserialize a different data from the original data? You are removing "illegal" xml characters... but they were present in the original data...

Comment: @xanatos Yes, beacause the original data is purged after deserialization i send data to server. the problem if dont act like that all the process is blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("XMLFile1.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
{
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ScanTransaction));
    ScanTransaction result = (ScanTransaction)s.Deserialize(xtr);
}
```

You don't even neeed a "special" `StreamReader`. The `XmlTextReader` doesn't check for illegal characters (you can control this with the `Normalize` boolean property, but it is by default `false`, so no check on illegal characters)